# How can i pass a DS.PromiseObject as the model in the link-to helper?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

So i have the following models:

```
var User = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  defaultRealm: DS.belongsTo('realm', { async: true })
 }); 

var Realm = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

My router and route look like:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('index', { path: '/:user_id' });
  this.route('realm', { path: '/realms/:realm_id' });
});

App.UserRoute = Em.Route.extend(
  model: function (params) {
    return this.store.find('user', params.user_id);
  },
  setupController: function (controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
  }
);
```

And in my index template i have the following:

```
{{#link-to 'realm' model.defaultRealm}}
    Realm  
{{/link-to}}
```

Now everything works as expected except that the `link-to` generates a url like `/realms/<App.RealmModel:ember728:541ddd0f29909d0000b6d407>` instead of `/realms/541ddd0f29909d0000b6d407`. It looks like instead of serializing the `id` of the model it's serializing the entire `DS.Model` object (`defaultRealm` is actually a `PromiseObject` due to the relationship being async). What's going on here?

**Current workaround:**

Use an observer on the controller and use `realmId` in the template. Is this really necessary?

```
App.IndexController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  realmId: null,
  modelObserver: Em.observer('model', function () {
    var self = this;
    self.get('model.defaultRealm').then(function (realm) {
      self.set('realmId', realm.get('id'));
    });
  });
});
```

**Versions:**

```
ember#1.7.0
ember-data#1.0.0-beta.10
handlebars#1.3.0
```

Comment: I'm going to assume the link-to `realms` is a typo, and should be link-to `realm`

Comment: @Kingpin2k yes it's supposed to be `realm`. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building the url it uses the serialize hook to find the `realm_id` on the route.  You can easily work around this by using the id, there is likely something else wrong with it, but I'll have to play with it later.

```
{{#link-to 'realms' defaultRealm.id}}
    Realm  
{{/link-to}}
```

Example with async: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/1107/edit

Comment: Using `defaultRealm.id` results in the exact same url :S